# How to get a general-employment visa for Germany as a programmer?

Tags: visa, germany

I accepted a job offer for position of front-end developer from a Berlin-based company and went to apply for a qualified-specialist visa. As per procedure, I sent my diploma to ZAB, ... and was turned down. ZAB believes that my Canadian diploma with study hours equivalent of a 3-year program does not amount to higher education.

My only chance to get visa is to apply for a general-employment visa for the whitelisted occupation *programmer.* So far, I have not seen anybody who managed to get a general-employment visa in that occupation. Is there any info online that covers getting visa through this route?

Comment: There is phletora of "diplomas" and "certificates" which you can gain from non-EU schools which are not considered "higher education" in the EU. This is partly due to the fact that countries which do not have the concept of "Ausbildung" (vocational training on the job) call absolutely everything "study".

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the information about visas at your local German embassy. Since you have a Canadian diploma, that would be http://www.canada.diplo.de/Vertretung/kanada/en/03/working.html

Here is a faq about [recoginition in Germany](https://www.anerkennung-in-deutschland.de/html/en/faq.php)

Since your already have a job try calling the embassy.